# Pytorch torch.load ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to load a pretrained model with torch.load.

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

I've checked that the path I am using is correct by opening it from the command line. What could be causing this?

Here's my code:

```
import torch
import sys

PATH = './gan.pth'

model = torch.load(PATH)
model.eval()
```

EDIT:
Entire error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = torch.load(PATH)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\pytorch-flask\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 595, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\pytorch-flask\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 774, in _legacy_load
    result = unpickler.load()
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are able to run this particular file (without `model = torch.load(PATH); model.eval()`)? Any other dependencies (imports) you haven't mentionned?

Comment: @Ivan Yes. Without the last two lines the file runs.

Comment: Can you give us the entire error stack?

Comment: @Ivan added to the bottom of the post

Comment: Do you have any idea how this `.pth` was file saved (which function was used)?

Comment: probably using ```torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)``` or is there another way?

Comment: I think the answer lies here https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/3678 

I could solve `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vocab'` with 

```import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './WordLM')```

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT** this answer doesn't provide the answer for the question but addresses another issue in the given code

the `.pth` file just stores the parameters of a model, not the model itself. When you want to load a model you will need the `.pt/-h` file and the python code of your model class. Then you can load it like this:

```py
# your model
class YourModel(nn.Modules):
    def __init__(self):
        super(YourModel, self).__init__()
        . . .

    def forward(self, x):
        . . .

# the pytorch save-file in which you stored your trained model
model_file = "<your path>"

model = Model()
model = model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_file))

model.eval()
```

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't provide an answer to the question. The issue seems to be with `model = torch.load(PATH)`. We can't guess what's inside that `.pth`...

Comment: yes I just noticed that the error doesnt come from that

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same exact error and was wondering what the problem was.
Turns out the problem is that the data saved with `torch.load()` needed the module `utils`.

Example:

```
from utils import some_function 
model = some_function()
torch.save(model)
```

When saving with torch in the given example, it recognizes that the module utils was used to get the desired data. Thus, when loading the '.pth' file, you need to import that same module `utils`.